# How can I make walls immune to fire damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage, damage-types, immunities

What options are there, preferably but not necesarilly through using the Abjuration school of magic, to make sure that the walls of a room are completely immune to fire damage, and thus incapable of being burnt down, melted, or anything of the sort?

If the walls are made *completely* indestructible by a proposed method, then that of course also fulfills the above criteria.

Comment: Does it have to be a solid wall? Does it have to be able to support things? Can it have gaps? How long does it have to last? For example, fire damage can’t do anything to *wall of fire*, but I doubt that’s what you had in mind.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143139/8610)

Comment: What's your use case? The correct answers are very different if you're playing a wizard and preparing to defend a town against a dragon, versus if you're a DM designing a dungeon and need to prevent the players from digging straight into the room with the treasure.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/180431). Can you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish here by having a wall that is immune to fire damage?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer is to make the walls using *wall of force*, which "is immune to damage of all kinds" and can be made permanent using the *permanency* spell.

Note that this will not handle the floor and ceiling without a DM ruling since *wall of force* only generates vertical walls. If you need floor and ceiling coverage, you could use *forcecage*, but this spell can't be made permanent.

The *energy immunity* spell targets only creatures, so it will not work on the walls unless you go to a lot of effort to make the walls count as creatures. (Perhaps strike a bargain with a small tribe of mimics to act as walls for you?)

Another approach would be to simply use a special material for the walls. The [special materials index](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?442820-Special-Materials-Index) lists something called "fyrite" which is immune to fire.

Most DMs would probably allow a material like obsidian or red dragon scale to work as well.

Comment: _Dark Way_ functions almost identically, but is a second level spell. Don't be fooled by the RAI for making bridges, the RAW clearly allows it to make walls. On the topic of ceilings, what is a ceiling if not a bridge between walls?

Comment: Good find, but I think the duration is too short to be viable here. (Especially given the number of castings that would be required to cover a room!)

Comment: Actually, the energy immunity enchantment in SBG does affect the walls and ceiling and floor, but only from effects originating outside the Stronghold space. Or are you meaning some other effect?

Comment: Thanks for catching, I deleted that section.

Answer (score 1):

#### There is partial immunity, and there is complete immunity, but the latter is more challenging....

**Partial Immunity**:
Stronghold Builder's Guidebook page 86: Zone of Elemental Immunity + Obdurium walls + Augment Object + Elemental Protection, Greater.

This Stronghold Space enchantment makes the entire space immune to one type of energy damage from any source outside of the space. Cited specifically is making a Stronghold immune to fire and floating it on a lake of lava.

Add obdurium walls for the best hardness, and boost it with the Augment Object effect to increase it. Every little bit helps especially when hardness is not fully effective against energy attacks.

Then enchant the walls with Elemental Protection, Greater for added resistance from any fire sources originating from within the Stronghold space.

This is pretty good, but there is a way to make it completely immune....

---

#### Alternatively, you could get clever and go for Complete Immunity...

If you want complete immunity one could cunningly arrange the building such that the walls in question are on the edge of, but within the area of effect of, multiple Zones of Immunity, with the spot the players are standing on outside of the Zones. Note that this is possible because Stronghold Spaces are flexible in shape, so long as the volume adds up to 20'x20'x20', thus allowing one to pull off the precise placement needed for this trick. Behind the walls can even be solid, as nothing says a given Stronghold space has to be a room, or can't be solid.

Therefore, any attempt to burn the walls would fail, technically coming from outside the enchanted zone.

This sort of arrangement would possibly be a very wasteful and ineffective use of space, depending on how much time you are planning on spending on the blueprints... but it would work for the desired intent.

Answer (score 1):

The creator of the dungeon could have also researched a unique spell: *energy immunity for objects*

If you are having to reeeaally stretch how to accomplish something, use the completely-by-the-book spell research system. Remaking energy immunity but with application to non-living objects instead of creatures is extremely straightforward. In fact, if you limited the spell to only work on, as an example, non-magical stone, it could actually be a lower-level spell.

Answer (score 0):

Stronghold Builder's Guide page 39, while it won't make them completely immune to fire damage it's near enough.

> Elemental Protection: This magic augmentation causes the wall to
>   absorb the first 60 points of damage from a specific energy type
>   (acid, cold, electricity, fire, or sonic) per day. If all 60 points of
>   protection are expended, they return 24 hours later, if the wall is
>   still there. The improved version of this augmentation absorbs the
>   first 120 points of damage from a specific energy type (acid, cold,
>   electricity, fire, or sonic) per day. Caster Level: 5th (elemental
>   protection), 10th (improved elemental protection); Prerequisites:
>   Craft Wondrous Item, protection from elements; Market Price: 7,500
>   gp (elemental protection), 15,000 gp (improved elemental
>   protection).